# Storing VSCode project in google drive? 100% cpu usage

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

I'm following the trailhead to try and setup vs code Salesforce extensions.
[Trailhead link](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quickstart-vscode-salesforce/use-vscode-for-salesforce)

After authenticating with my playground org and trying to create an apex class, I noticed it was running extremely slow.  I checked task manager and noticed my cpu was pegged at 100%.

I then noticed my google drive was stuck syncing an "Apex.db" file.  Sure enough, killing google drive - specifically Google drive file stream, made everything go back to normal.  Also, just disabling the Salesforce extension pack also makes cpu usage go back to normal.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to store projects here for access from other pc's.  I tried making the folder available offline, which didn't help.

A couple of questions around this issue.

1) Can project folders be stored in a cloud drive for syncing?
2) If not, how can I close / delete / move the current project folder within vs code?  Or, do I just have to delete the folder from file explorer.

I'm running windows 10 x64 professional with latest version of vscode and all salesforce extensions (installed on 1/14/20).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar idea or annoyance in past with storing local project to cloud, after using git version control things are much simpler and this approach is recommended.

Not only GIT allows you to work on multiple computer but also with a team. Basic version of popular source control like Github/Gitlabs/Bitbucket is free.

Continuous auto sync with google drive is much heavier for processor.

You could refer to this trailhead module to learn more: [Develop an App with Salesforce CLI and Source Control](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/develop-app-with-salesforce-cli-and-source-control)

Comment: Great! I'll give this trailhead a shot.  Any solution that allows me to access my projects from various machines will work.

Comment: As an update, I posted this as a github issue and the response was to store projects in a version control system instead.